Pass docker environment-vars to vite(svelte) docker-compose stack
I am trying to get docker-compose to pass env vars to my svelte(kit) app running on vite development server.
I'm packaging my web app as a Docker image like this:
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
ARG VITE_SERVER_HOST
ENV VITE_SERVER_HOST=$VITE_SERVER_HOST
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app .
RUN npm install
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ARG VITE_SERVER_HOST
ENV VITE_SERVER_HOST=$VITE_SERVER_HOST
ENTRYPOINT [ "" ]
CMD ["node", "build"]

My docker compose configuration for the web application looks like this:
  web:
    container_name: songrex-web
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      args:
        - VITE_SERVER_HOST=<URL>
    environment:
      - PORT=5173
      - ORIGIN=<URL>
    build: web
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    depends_on:
      - server

I'm trying to access the env var on the web app like this (but the value is never set):
const hosturl = (import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_HOST || "server") + ":3000";

How can I import this ENV-VAR to my web app over docker-compose?

The problem is that environment variables are injected by Vite during the build phase, however you're attempting to set them in the runtime using docker compose; which does not work because those are just HTML and Javascript files hosted locally.
Vite server (which is what you have configured in docker compose) is for local development only as a means to serve the statically built files.

well, vite is the only "default" way for production builds in SvelteKit. I have not seen any other way to deploy my Frontend without Vite-Building it. Is there any alternative I can use or how are SvelteKit Stacks usually configured in docker-compose?

anyways, how would you recommend me to get my docker-compose env vars into my project to let my frontend on the clientside use the vars?

ore maybe, is there any way to connect my backend to my frontend with a custom adapter or something like mentioned in the sveltekit docs? I do not really understand much about how this works
